# Javascript array when referenced errors with object not found

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to retrieve the data from a ADO recordset and load it into an array using javascript.

The data seems to be loading in fine ( as the alert shows the correct length) but when i try to reference one of the object values it give the following "Object is no longer valid"

The code is as follows

```
var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");   
var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 
var db_name = "C:\\HMRC\\xxx.accdb";
var csv = "user_id, date_corrected, tot_corrected \n";
var rec_obj = {};



function get_record()
{

    var i = 0 ;
    var master_arr = [];

    adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + db_name);
    adoRS.Open("Select * From tot_corr_ent", adoConn, 1, 3);


    while (!adoRS.eof)
    {

        rec_obj["user_id"] = adoRS.Fields("user_id");
        rec_obj["date_corrected"] = adoRS.Fields("date_corrected");
        rec_obj["tot_ent"] = adoRS.Fields("tot_ent");

        master_arr.push(rec_obj);

        adoRS.MoveNext;

        i++;

    }

    alert ( "Out of the loop ");    

    adoRS.close();
    adoConn.close();

    alert ( "connection closed ");  

    alert("Final alert: " + master_arr.length);

    alert("Final alert 2: " + master_arr[0].user_id);  -- **errors at this line**
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Objects are copied using reference. so every push , you add same object with different value. So essentially, you are adding last object `n` times. Try defining `rec_obj ` inside while

Comment: Thank you Rajesh ! I found the solution where i missed ".value" keyword for retrieving the data from the recordset and also putting the rec_obj inside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is likely to be because you are storing a reference to the ADODB `Field` and not the value. This reference goes out of scope when you closed the connection. You need to copy the value you want from the `Field` object into your object. I don't know ADODB but it looks like you need to access the `Value` property of the `Field`

As @Rajesh said in his comment you are adding n copies of the same reference into `master_arr`. Change the `while` loop to:

```
while (!adoRS.eof) {
    var rec_obj = {}
    rec_obj["user_id"] = adoRS.Fields("user_id").Value;
    rec_obj["date_corrected"] = adoRS.Fields("date_corrected").Value;
    rec_obj["tot_ent"] = adoRS.Fields("tot_ent").Value;

    master_arr.push(rec_obj);

    adoRS.MoveNext;

    i++;

}
```